Loop through object and display matching value from another array
I have an object (categorizedDatas2) like so:
{
    "Mike": {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "EQLwvDPfgLyXk5c7Bbr0",
                "Category": "01. SAFETY",
                "CategoryId": "default-090",
                "SubCategory": "PLBS & EPIRBS",
                "SubCategoryId": "default-093",
                "Name": "T610G PLB",
                "Brand": "GME",
                "Owner": "Bob",
                "RealOwner": "Bob",
                "packingLocation": "To Pack",
                "Quantity": 1,
                "Weight": 0.16,
                "Status": "Ready"
            },
            {
                "id": "90952450-0c6b-11ec-90f3-ff0167255365",
                "Category": "05. HIKE",
                "CategoryId": "default-050",
                "SubCategory": "POLES",
                "SubCategoryId": "default-054",
                "Name": "Carbon Z Poles - Large",
                "Brand": "BLACK DIAMOND",
                "Owner": "Dave",
                "RealOwner": "Dave",
                "packingLocation": "Wear",
                "Quantity": 1,
                "Weight": 0.3,
                "Status": "Ready"
            }
        ]
    }
}

The Category name attached to each item has been changed - so it stores the CategoryId of the original item so we can look it up to get the changed name.
These details are held in a different array (newata), and I am using:
const getCategoryPackedAlt = (key) => {
  const foundCategorykey = categorizedDatas2[key].items[0].CategoryId
  const foundCategory = newata?.GearCategories?.find((element) => element.id == foundCategorykey)
  if (foundCategory) {
  return foundCategory.label
  } else {
    return '-'
  }
}

This works but it only returns the first item Category name and shows for all items.
In my map I use:
{getCategoryPackedAlt(key)}

How can I loop through each item in categorizedDatas2 and show the correct Category name?
